# How to run-android a shoutem clone project?

Tags: react-native, shoutem

When I react-native run-android a shoutem clone project, first it was showing a development server error code 500..I changed the react-native and babel preset for react native from package.json. And now there is no error but the app crashes right after build. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: can you add shoutem linked

Comment: I just cloned the project and tried to run it. I havent linked anything manually.